# Does Type Hints improve performance in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say we have the following code:

```
def hello(name: str) -> str:
    return 'Hello there, {}!'.format(name)
```

So I was curious about this type hints and I took a look at PEP docs:

> While these annotations are available at runtime through the usual
> `__annotations__` attribute, no type checking happens at runtime. Instead, the proposal assumes the existence of a separate off-line
> type checker which users can run over their source code voluntarily.

Here's my question: can we take advantage of type hints to make python programs run faster?

Comment: Faster than what?

Comment: Type Hints is aimed at improving [Static Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) capabilities.

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question, but there is a dupe. The answer is bascially no

Comment: In its current state, type hints are for writing code which is more robust, not code which is faster. A natural future evolution might see such type hints used for byte code optimization.

Comment: dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41692473/does-python-type-hint-annotations-cause-some-run-time-effects

Comment: No, if you use the python interpreter to execute your code. But if you compile your code (like using Nuitka, Cython, etc.. ) then the compiler may use that extra info to generate more optimized code.