# Does the use of type hints in Python have an impact on performance?

Tags: python, performance

I recently read [this article](https://hackernoon.com/why-is-python-so-slow-e5074b6fe55b) that says that the main reason for Python to lose some performance is due to of its dynamic nature, but will the new PEP related to type hints cause an improvement in the performance like the use of [Cython](http://cython.org/) or similar?

In case of no, is this planned to be implemented in a future?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python type hint (annotations) cause some run-time effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41692473/does-python-type-hint-annotations-cause-some-run-time-effects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type hints, just like, comments, do not have any inherent performance benefits. Look at this [link](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#non-goals)

From the above link -

> While the proposed typing module will contain some building blocks for runtime type checking -- in particular the get_type_hints() function -- third party packages would have to be developed to implement specific runtime type checking functionality, for example using decorators or metaclasses. Using type hints for performance optimizations is left as an exercise for the reader.
>
> It should also be emphasized that Python will remain a dynamically typed language, and the authors have no desire to ever make type hints mandatory, even by convention.

Also, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41692473/does-python-type-hint-annotations-cause-some-run-time-effects) answer