# Why do type annotations make Python code slower?

Tags: python, performance, type-hinting

These are results of my tests in `ipython`.

For `int`:

```py
In [2]: %time for _  in range(1000): exec('a: int = 4')                                                                                                                         
CPU times: user 12.2 ms, sys: 12 µs, total: 12.2 ms
Wall time: 12.2 ms

In [3]: %time for _  in range(1000): exec('a = 4')                                                                                                                              
CPU times: user 9.5 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 9.5 ms
Wall time: 9.54 ms
```

And for `str`:

```py
In [4]: %time for _  in range(1000): exec('a: str = "hello"')                                                                                                                   
CPU times: user 13.3 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 13.3 ms
Wall time: 13.4 ms

In [5]: %time for _  in range(1000): exec('a = "hello"')                                                                                                                        
CPU times: user 10.4 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 10.4 ms
Wall time: 10.4 ms
```

And also for `list`:

```py
In [6]: %time for _  in range(1000): exec('a: list = [1,2, "hello"]')                                                                                                           
CPU times: user 19.1 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 19.1 ms
Wall time: 21.5 ms

In [7]: %time for _  in range(1000): exec('a = [1,2, "hello"]')                                                                                                                 
CPU times: user 15.8 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 15.8 ms
Wall time: 15.8 ms
```

I know theorically there should not be any difference in `list` or `int` annotations, while there is no functionality regarding to them. But I just tested these types to make sure that using type hints slows down the execution by about 25 percent. Why is this? As far as I know type hints do nothing with executing. Just spending more time to parse them and adding them to the `__annotations__` dictionary makes this huge difference in execution time?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41692943/10858217 You can check this answer for reference

Comment: In your example the code is doing next to nothing, so parsing and adding to `__annotations__` is a large proportion of the total time spent.

Comment: This is why correct use of timeit separates compiletime from runtime so you don't get this kind of spillover effect. Why would anyone care how long it takes to compile a line of code a thousand times?

Comment: If you `compile()` the code object beforehand, then `exec` the code object, I find a smaller difference, but there still seems to be a difference

Comment: Use the `dis` module to see the byte code generated by each.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Interesting, why is that? doesn't the `exec` first compile and then execute?

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi well, yes, so the compilation step takes more time, but that would only happen once in a  program, so normally, you don't worry about it. Especially in a language like Python with minimal compilation penalty (although, it can still matter in certain cases where you aren't executing pre-compiled code and you want to execute a small python utitlity many times, for exmaple)

Comment: @chepner yeah, I did it right now and see the difference. But the difference is really much more than what I thought. I always considered type-hints as some thing without any performance side-effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method is testing the compilation time of interpreting the raw string version of the python code into something that is executable. If you were to instead use timeit with fucntions, you wouldn't see a noticeable difference:

```
import timeit


def method1():
    for _ in range(1000): a: int = 4


def method2():
    for _ in range(1000): a = 4


print(timeit.timeit(method1, number=200000))
print(timeit.timeit(method2, number=200000))
```

```
2.8046581
2.8103205999999994
```

Comment: If I do `dis.dis('a: int = 4')`, I see instructions regarding the annotation. If I do `dis.dis(method1)`, I don't see them. It shows the same as `dis.dis(method2)`. So it might be not about compilation vs execution but rather about compilation vs somehow different compilation.

Comment: @Kelly `dis.dis('def g(y:int):\n b:float=1.2\n def f(x:int): a:int=4\nc:int=7')`  -> Type hints on all non-fast (global) variable declarations, and on all function/method declarations , nested or not, cost time.  Most serious though is how ugly and disturbing they are and seriously affect readability.  Comment type hints, sparringly used, can solve both these problem.